# How to find product before_save Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've app where I've got Ingredients and also have deliveries of `Ingredients`, after delivery ingredient is increasing value. I have a problem to find `Ingredient` before save.

On my delivery I store ingredient_id so I should have a in my controller function to find Ingredient via

before_save :find_ingredient

```
private
def find_ingredient
    self.find_ingredient = find(:ingredient_id)
end
```

How to find this Ingredient before_save?
In my controller

```
  if @delivery.save

    @ingredient.quantity += @delivery.unloaded
    @ingredient.save
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private

def find_ingredient
    Ingredient.find(:ingredient_id).increment!(:quantity)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd do something like this:

```
#app/models/delivery.rb
class Delivery < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :ingredient, inverse_of: :deliveries
   before_save :increase_ingredient

   private

   def increase_ingredient
      ingredient.increment! :quantity, unloaded
   end
end
```

Comment: Connecting two answers together works! Thanks 
 def find_ingredient
         Ingredient.find(ingredient_id)
         ingredient.increment! :quantity, unloaded
    end